# Do maven plugins need dependencies?

Tags: maven

Does Maven install the necessary dependencies when adding a plugin to the pom file?

For example, when adding the following code to a pom file, does maven download the necessary dependencies for that plugin?

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
      </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** to both questions.  Sub-dependencies are called ***Transitive Dependencies*** and are handled natively in Maven 2.0.  You can read about it more [on the Maven website](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

### Specifically:

> Transitive dependencies are a new feature in Maven 2.0. This allows
>   you to avoid needing to discover and specify the libraries that your
>   own dependencies require, and including them automatically.
>
> This feature is facilitated by reading the project files of your
>   dependencies from the remote repositories specified. In general, all
>   dependencies of those projects are used in your project, as are any
>   that the project inherits from its parents, or from its dependencies,
>   and so on.
>
> There is no limit to the number of levels that dependencies can be
>   gathered from, and will only cause a problem if a cyclic dependency is
>   discovered.
>
> With transitive dependencies, the graph of included libraries can
>   quickly grow quite large. For this reason, there are some additional
>   features that will limit which dependencies are included:
>
> - **Dependency mediation** - this determines what version of a dependency will be used when multiple versions of an artifact are
>     encountered. Currently, Maven 2.0 only supports using the "nearest
>     definition" which means that it will use the version of the closest
>     dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies. You can always
>     guarantee a version by declaring it explicitly in your project's POM.
>     Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the
>     dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would
>     win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that
>     counts: the first declaration wins.
>
>   - ***"nearest definition"*** means that the version used will be the closest one to your project in the tree of dependencies, eg. if
>       dependencies for A, B, and C are defined as A -> B -> C -> D 2.0 and A
>       -> E -> D 1.0, then D 1.0 will be used when building A because the path from A to D through E is shorter. You could explicitly add a
>       dependency to D 2.0 in A to force the use of D 2.0
> - **Dependency management** - this allows project authors to directly specify the versions of artifacts to be used when they are encountered
>     in transitive dependencies or in dependencies where no version has
>     been specified. In the example in the preceding section a dependency
>     was directly added to A even though it is not directly used by A.
>     Instead, A can include D as a dependency in its dependencyManagement
>     section and directly control which version of D is used when, or if,
>     it is ever referenced.
> - **Dependency scope** - this allows you to only include dependencies appropriate for the current stage of the build. This is described in
>     more detail below.
> - **Excluded dependencies** - If project X depends on project Y, and project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project X can explicitly
>     exclude project Z as a dependency, using the "exclusion" element.
>     Optional dependencies - If project Y depends on project Z, the owner
>     of project Y can mark project Z as an optional dependency, using the
>     "optional" element. When project X depends on project Y, X will depend
>     only on Y and not on Y's optional dependency Z. The owner of project X
>     may then explicitly add a dependency on Z, at her option. (It may be
>     helpful to think of optional dependencies as "excluded by default.")

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the plugin pom

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-maven-plugin/2.7/sonar-maven-plugin-2.7.pom

Maven will pull all relevant dependencies for the plugin according to

```
<dependencies>
```

section of the plugin pom